# Event change is not triggered if the readonly flag is set to true

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using readonly configuration in my child element. But i also have configured notify to true. But, the value is not getting updated in my parent and child elements when the child(my-subelement) is updated. This works fine if the readonly flag is set to false.
How to fire events for readonly property.

```
//my-element.html
<link rel="import" href="../../../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../my-subelement/my-subelement.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">
<template>
    <div class="div-content">
        <div class="data-content">
            String Value 
            <my-subelement id="subelement" input-value="{{inputValue}}">
            </my-subelement>
        </div>
        <div class="data-content">
            String Data: <input type="text" value={{inputValue::input}}>
        </div>
        <div class="data-content">
            The string value is: <span>{{inputValue}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>         
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        properties: {
            inputValue: {
                type: String,
                value: function() {
                    return 'Test';
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>


//my-subelement.html
<link rel="import" href="../../../polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-subelement">
<template>
    <h1>
        <div class="data-content">
            String Data: <input type="text" value={{inputValue::input}}>
        </div>
        <div class="data-content">
            The string value is: <span>{{inputValue}}</span>
        </div>
    </h1>
 </template>
 <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-subelement',
        properties: {
            inputValue: {
                type: String,
                notify: true,
                readOnly: true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Please help me understand with an example snippet

Thanks

Comment: I don't know polymer, but how is updated your input if it's set as read-only? And for that matter, it might be useful to know how it is updated when you say that it works without this attribute. (per specs, the change event should be triggered only by user's action, not scripts.)

Comment: the read-only attribute in polymer is used to restrict the changes from host to target. But, it should allow the changes from target to host if the notify attribute is set to true. And the event trigger is happening in this line "{{inputValue::input}}"